# C++ Exceptions Throw Empty Class

Tags: c++, exception, empty-class

Below is an excerpt from "Programming: Principles and Practice Using C++". I'm confused by the **throw Bad_area()** notation. The book tries to explain it, "Bad_area() means 'Make an object of type Bad_area'," continuing with that it then throws that type. This explanation is not congruent with the assignment notation, eg. **int x=1 == int x(1);** or **Bad_area x;**.

Example code (commented out the try-block):

```
class Bad_area {}; // a type specifically for reporting errors from area()

// calculate area of a rectangle
// throw a Bad_area exception in case of a bad argument
int area(int length, int width)
{
  if (length<=0 || width<=0) throw Bad_area();
  return length*width;
}

int main()
try {
  // ...
}
catch (Bad_area) {
  cout << "Oop! bad arguments to area()\n";
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Bad_area()` is a explicit call to the default constructor of the class `Bad_area`.
That is, what `throw Bad_area()` does is to return (throw) directly an anonimus instance of the class `Bad_area`.

Is the same as in OO languages like Java or C#, when you return a instance directly. For example:

```
void foo() throws MyException
{
    if( error ) throw new MyException();
}
```

Note that that explicit calls to constructors are rarelly used in C++, because the lifetime of the instances is based on RAII.
There are only a few cases where a explicit call is a good idea, most of them are like your example, return statements. For example a `point_2d` class wich algebraic methods are easilly inlined:

```
struct point_2d
{
    float x;
    float y;

    point_2d(float _x = 0.0f , float _y = 0.0f) : x( _x ) , y( _y ) {}

    //Easy inlineable addition:
    point_2d operator+(const point_2d& lhs , const point_2d& rhs)
    {
        return point_2d{ lhs.x + rhs.x , lhs.y + rhs.y };
    } 
};
```

On the other hand, execpt that exceptional cases, **direct calls to constructors must be avoided**. Its common to see newebbies C++ code with a Java style. For example:

```
int main()
{
    point_2d* point = new point_2d( 10.0f , 10.0f ); //Ok, this is not exactly a call to
                                                     //to the ctor, but has the same meaning.
                                                     //WTF why you use dynamic memory here?
}
```

Or a correct C++ variable declaration, followed by a Java initialization:

```
int main()
{
    point_2d point;

    point = point_2d( 10.0f , 10.0f ); //WTF!!!
}
```

Depending on the compiler, or if the optimizations are turned off (Everybody knows that noobs never enable optimizations...), this result in:

- A call to point_2d constructor (The explicit call)
- A call to `point_2d::operator=`
- A call to point_2d destructor (Destruction of the temporal created by the ctor call).

Or, finally, the same but everything in the same line:

```
int main()
{
    point_2d point = point_2d( 10.0f , 10.0f ); //WTF!!!
}
```

That is a call to the point_2d constructor followed by a call to the point_2d copy constructor to initialize the variable with the created temporal.

Note that performance in this case is not the point, because **thats not the C++ stye/way to do things**. Everybody who writes C++ code in that way, should go to buy [a good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). *Effective C++* was redited with upcoming Java-like programmers in mind.

Comment: Is that to say I should drop the parens to make it a simple throw of **Bad_are** instead of the constructor? I'm not sure how they would be different, unless the default constructor did something I didn't know about.

Comment: @user2684847 no, you can't drop off the parens. You didn't get the point. `throw Bad_area;` is ill formed, because `Bad_area` is a type, not an instance. What we do with `throw Bad_area()` is to return (Throw) the **instance generated by the call to the constructor**.

Comment: Oh I see, it's like a temporary/anonymous/un-named instance (I learned it as an "object") of **Bad_area** which is then passed as an argument to the `catch(Bad_area)`. Book doesn't cover this.

Comment: @JayAdams exactly, that is :). *"The book doesn't cover this"* I'm sure that it covers that in other chapter, or is covered in other good C++ books. Anyway, if you have other mistakes, log in to SO and search a question about that.  Please upvote and accept the answer